# Alphabetical sorting pretty slow

Tags: java, android, sorting, alphabetical

Here is my problem : I have a list of custom object which contain a String called label. This list is big but too big, around 1000 objects. I would like to do an alphabetical sorting using `label`.

The thing is, some `label` contains character like for example `É`, `(`, `e` or `E` as first character. So I had to use the function `deAccent()` found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1214937/7802894) to sort it independently of the accent or other thing like that. With the use of this function the list `['Gab','eaaa','Éaa']` is sorted like that `['eaaa','Éaa','Gab']` instead of `['eaaa','Gab','Éaa']`. Because when we use the `compareTo` method, `É` is after `G`. Here is what I have :

```
private List<Formula> sortFormulaList(List<Formula> formulaList) {
    // Sort all label alphabetically
    if (formulaList.size() > 0) {
        Collections.sort(formulaList, (formula1, formula2) ->
                deAccent(formula1.getLabel()).toLowerCase().compareTo(deAccent(formula2.getLabel().toLowerCase())));
    }
    return formulaList;
}

private String deAccent(String str) {
    String nfdNormalizedString = Normalizer.normalize(str, Normalizer.Form.NFD);
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\p{InCombiningDiacriticalMarks}+");
    return pattern.matcher(nfdNormalizedString).replaceAll("");
}
```

If I don't use the `deAccent()` it is fast enough for my purpose but when I use it take like 1 to 3 seconds to being sort.

Any idea on how I could make such a sort ? Or make this one faster

Comment: what are you trying to do in the deAccent method.Perhaps it can be optimized

Comment: You can, for example, precompile the pattern instead of compiling it every invocation.

Comment: @VenkataNarayanaMalireddy I edited my post to make it more clear

Comment: The comparator will be called O(n log n) times on average. Therefore if you preprocess the data such that deAccent is called only once per object you get a nice speedup.

Comment: Thanks @Glains, by doing a precompilation of the pattern it's faster, almost like without deAccent()

Comment: What do you mean by preprocess the data @Henry ?

Comment: @YohannLereclus store the de-accented string value with each object.

Comment: Oh okay I understand. Thanks a lot guys !

Comment: Within `Formula`, instead of adding `String getDeAccetendLabel()`, consider adding something like `static Comparator<Formula> getLabelComparator()`.  This will limit the exposure of the unaccented label class field.

Comment: I'm not sure I understood @AndrewS, I'm not really familiar with the `Comparator<>`
I should define a `Comparator<Formula> labelComparator` in my Formula object ? But how do I instantiate it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider @Henry's excellent suggestion and `Formula` might look like this:

```
public class Formula {
    private final String label;
    private final String deAccentedLabel;

    public Formula(String label) {
        this.label = label;
        this.deAccentedLabel = deAccent(label);
    }

    public String getLabel() {
        return label;
    }

    public String getDeAccentedLabel() {
        return comparableLabel;
    }


    private String deAccent(String str) {
        String nfdNormalizedString = Normalizer.normalize(str, Normalizer.Form.NFD);
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\p{InCombiningDiacriticalMarks}+");
        return pattern.matcher(nfdNormalizedString).replaceAll("");
    }

}
```

Then it can be used like this:

```
Collections.sort(formulaList, (formula1, formula2) -> formula1.getDeAccentedLabel().toLowerCase().compareTo(formula2.getDeAccentedLabel().toLowerCase());
```

However, this exposes `deAccentedLabel` by adding the `public getDeAccentedLabel()` method.

What I was suggesting in the comment is to hide `deAccentedLabel` to keep the public interface of `Formula` as clean as possible.  So to sort, `Formula` provides the Comparator **instead of other classes having to build it**.  `Formula` would look something like this:

```
public class Formula {
    private final String label;
    private final String comparableLabel;

    public Formula(String label) {
        this.label = label;
        this.comparableLabel = deAccent(label).toLowerCase();
    }

    public String getLabel() {
        return label;
    }

    private String deAccent(String str) {
        String nfdNormalizedString = Normalizer.normalize(str, Normalizer.Form.NFD);
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\p{InCombiningDiacriticalMarks}+");
        return pattern.matcher(nfdNormalizedString).replaceAll("");
    }

    public static Comparator<Formula> getLabelComparator() {
        return (formula1, formula2) -> formula1.comparableLabel.compareTo(formula2.comparableLabel);
    }

}
```

and used like this:

```
Collections.sort(formulaList, Formula.getLabelComparator());
```

Comment: Okay I see! That's a thing is never did, thanks a lot !